# What is a good Primer on the subject of Physics?

Tags: resource-recommendations

There are a lot of textbooks available for this subject, however what is "the best" (IYO) textbook/reference guide? This is assuming the student has zero background in the subject and simply wants to have the different disciplines briefly laid out and explained.

Comment: There is no single textbook that encompasses all of physics, not even on a superficial level. The times when that would have been possible are long gone.

Comment: @AcuriousMind: As in... 2500 years ago in ancient Greece? I am not even sure about that. It's a "yuge" subject. :-)

Comment: An FAQ was created at PSE based on numerous discussions at PSE for resource recommendations, did you bother to go through the site via the search option? Anyways, here is the [thread][1] . Alternatively, you can refer to [this][2] and/or [this][3] link as well.

[1]: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations
[2]: http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicphys.htm
[3]: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Administrivia/booklist.html